# How to remove <p> tags from WYGWAM

Tags: wygwam

I'd like to know how to remove automatic

wrapping tags that outputs in page.

```
<p class="summary">{sous_titre}</p>
```

This is what I wrote inside my template. As you can see, I already put myself a

tag with a class summary. But in the code source of my page, this is what I get

```
<p class="summary"></p>
<p>My text bla bla bla</p>
<p></p>
```

I really don't understand that messed up right there. Tho, I just wanted to output what's inside my wygwam..anyway, so I did some research around forums and found out that I should go in WYGWAM advanced settings and set autoParagraph to No. I did that and I still get the same f%^&* results.

Can anyone fixed this once?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the parameter text_only="yes" should sort you out. [Documentation.](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/templating/field.html#text-only-mode)

Comment: I vote this as the correct answer. (Sorry JChrono)

Comment: Wow. How did I pass through WYGWAM documentation without seeing it? Thanks a lot, this will help me a lot in many many many projects. Great answer!

Comment: It's ok, I derped. Just glad someone got it!

Comment: Matthieu Boisjoli, don't worry, you wouldn't believe how many times I went through the documentation before spotting it.

Answer (score 1):

You might go about this using an add-on, using [CE String](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-string) or free add-ons, [Remove HTML](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/remove-html), [SuperGeeky Tag Stripper](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/supergeekery-tag-stripper).

I use CE String personally, but the others will do just as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Channel Field Preferences]

Take a look at that channel field's settings. You need to edit this section to be "None". When you change it, **make** sure you say yes to reformatting all of your entries for channels that have that field group assigment to fix previous entries. To be safe, **back** up your channel_entries data tables before making this change.

But this will allow your text fields to output without p tags!

Comment: does this work? I waqs under the impression that WYGWAM puts surrounding `<p>` tags into it's saved value, prior to the Default Text Formatting thing?

Comment: Oh yeah lol.. @Matthew, just switch your field type to a regular (non-rich) textarea!

Comment: This isn't working. However, I thank you for your time and your answer. I accepted an answer which was found in WYGWAM documentation, pretty easy!